# Get value of MenuItem material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using [Material UI](https://material-ui.com/) for Menu and Menu Item.
I'm trying to get the value of a menu item, but it doesn't work.

This is my code :

```
<Menu value= { this.state.selectedItem }>
  <MenuItem onClick={this.listClicked} 
    leftIcon={
      <FontIcon 
        className="material-icons"
        style={{ color: 'white', margin: '0' }}>
          format_list_bulleted
      </FontIcon>
    }
  />     
  <MenuItem onClick={this.settingClicked} 
    leftIcon={
      <FontIcon 
        className="material-icons"
        style={{ color: 'white', margin: '0' }}>
          settings
      </FontIcon>
    } 
  />
</Menu>

public listClicked = (value) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedItem :value
  })
  console.log(this.state.selectedItem)
}
```

I don't get the value, and in the console of navigator I have an object.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 30):

Use a [data-attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_Access) on the menu item and access it from the `currentTarget` of the click event. Note that `data-my-value` attribute becomes `myValue` on `event.currentTarget.dataset`.

```
const handleClick = event => {
    const { myValue } = event.currentTarget.dataset;
    console.log(myValue) // --> 123
}

<MenuItem
    data-my-value={123}
    onClick={handleClick}
>
    <div>text</div>
</MenuItem>
```

**Why `currentTarget` instead of `target`?**
The `currentTarget` refers to the element that the event listener is directly attached to while the `target` refers to the specific element within MenuItem, such as some `div`, that is clicked on. That div does not have the `data-my-value` attribute and as such the `target` wouldn't have `myValue` on its `dataset`. So use `currentTarget` in this case.

Related: [How to access custom attributes from event object in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377837/how-to-access-custom-attributes-from-event-object-in-react)

Comment: not working for MUI 5

Comment: seems unlikely that it's related to mui 5. Are you using event.target or event.currentTarget? https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/3311#issuecomment-405831602

Comment: `event.currentTarget`

Comment: At this point it's going to mean to help you debug your code or prove to you it is or is not caused by mui5. Here is not the place for that. What you can do though is create a new (quality) question on SO. You might find yourself solving your code while doing that. Good luck!

Answer (score 8):

I used NativeEvent and it works for me.

```
handleClose = (ev) => {
        this.setState({
            anchorEl: null
        });
        console.log(ev.nativeEvent.target.outerText);
    };
```

Try like this please.

Answer (score 7):

In the Material UI `Menu` component, firing functions when selecting a menu item is best done with the `onChange` handler of the parent `Menu` component instead of `onClick` handlers for each separate item. The signature of the `onChange` callback is `function(event: object, value: any) => void`, so you can give each of your `MenuItem`s a separate `value` prop, and this will be available as the second argument in your `onChange` handler. Like this:

```js
<Menu value= { this.state.selectedItem } onChange={ this.menuClicked }>
  <MenuItem value="list" leftIcon={
    <FontIcon className="material-icons">format_list_bulleted</FontIcon>
  } />     
  <MenuItem value="settings" leftIcon={
    <FontIcon className="material-icons">settings</FontIcon>
  } />
</Menu>
```

...

```js
public menuClicked = (event, value) => {
  this.setState({
    selectedItem: value
  })
  console.log(this.state.selectedItem)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but like the answer of @Shubham khatri, I have a null value in my console, or an undifined .. I don't understand..

Comment: Are you sure you added the `value` prop to the `MenuItem`s?

Comment: I had to do `(event, { props: { value } }) => {
    console.log(value);
  };`

Answer (score 6):

Menu does not have onChange defined in the API and it did not work for me because it is never called. 
What works for me was an ugly solution:

`<MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose.bind(this, 'valueHere')}>Text here</MenuItem>`

Comment: also `e.currentTarget.outerText` for MUI 5.x

Answer (score 6):

Try `e.target.innerText` in `MenuItem` `onClick`.

```
const Menu = () => {
    const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null)

    const handleClick = event => {
        setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget)
    }

    const handleClose = e => {
        console.log(e.target.innerText) // => This logs menu item text.
        setAnchorEl(null)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Button onClick={handleClick}>Open Menu</Button>
            <Menu anchorEl={anchorEl} keepMounted open={Boolean(anchorEl)} onClose={handleClose}>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>Logout</MenuItem>
            </Menu>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a feature in JavaScript called `curry`

This is in menu

```
 <MenuItem  onClick={this.closeDrawer("ProductPage")}>
        Products
 </MenuItem>
```

This is in handler

```
closeDrawer = key => event => {
    console.log("=> closeDrawer key", key);
    this.setState({ open: false });
  };
```

Then you would see something like below in JavaScript console

```
=> closeDrawer key ProductPage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also get the value like this

```
<MenuItem key={menu.id} primaryText={menuItem.name} onClick = {this.onClickButton} menuItems = {this.subMenu(menuItem.children)}/>
```

and then onClickButton like this

```
onClickButton = (ev) => {
      if(ev.target.innerText === 'light') { // light is the value of menuitem in string
        this.props.dispatch(changeTheme('light'))
      } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter that is passed to the `onClick` handler is an `event` not a `value`. You have to extract the `value` from the event.

```
public listClicked = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            selectedItem :event.target.value
        },()=>{
       console.log(this.state.selectedItem)
        })
    }
```

Also move the `console.log` as a callback as that way it is called only after the `state` change has taken place.

Comment: The value is not an attribute of event.target.
event.target has a <li> element which contains the value. Getting it is not so easy.

Answer (score 0):

onClick is not specified as a property for MenuItem, you can put a onChange on `Menu` and get the value of the selected item like

```
  <Menu value= { this.state.selectedItem } onChange={this.selectedItem}
            <MenuItem leftIcon={
                <FontIcon className="material-icons" style={{ color: 'white', margin: '0' }}>format_list_bulleted</FontIcon>
            } />     

            <MenuItem leftIcon={
                <FontIcon className="material-icons" style={{ color: 'white', margin: '0' }}>settings</FontIcon>
            } />

        </Menu>


        selectedItem=(e, value)=> {
             this.setState({
                selectedItem :value
             }, () => {console.log(this.state.selectedItem)})
        }
```

Comment: If you still wanna use onClick on menuItem see @mrinalmech answer

Comment: Hi, thank you for your anwer, i'm trying your solution, but it doesn't work. In the console of the navigator I have an "undifined" .. An idea ? Thank you

Comment: Do you write the selectedItem function in the same component as Menu

Comment: can you console.log(e, value) in the selectedItem function

Comment: Yes, I have this : 
Proxy { <target>: Object, <handler>: Object } undefined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143790/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-anais-saez).

Answer (score 0):

Add a 'value' attribute to the **MenuItem** component. Then use the getAttribute() function to get the value of the 'value' attribute. Here's an example...

```
const someMenu = () => {
    const [element, setElement] = React.useState(null)

    const handleClose = event => {
       setElement(null)

       // grab the value of the "value" attribute here
       console.log(event.target.getAttribute("value")
    }

    const handleClick = event => {
       setElement(event.currentTarget)
    }

    return(
        <Menu anchorEl={element} keepMounted open={Boolean(element)}>
            <MenuItem value="foo" onClick={handle} />
        </Menu>
    )
}
```

Comment: What version of MUI are you using? This is not working for me.  I am getting: e.target.getAttribute is not a function