# How to get the name of the MenuItem on click using Menu and MenuItem from Material UI React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using Menu and Menu Item from MaterialUI in React. I want to print the name of the menu item when I click on it.

In the console.log event.currentTarget returns the entire list item: [ListItem Image attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGMDs.png)

In the console.log event.currentTarget.dataset returns the [DOMSTringMap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzwuX.png).
WRT a similar question I found: [Get value of MenuItem material ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43870814/get-value-of-menuitem-material-ui)
But the output of DOMStringMap seems unusable.

**Check the addMap function:**
I want to console.log the name of the menu item which is "ONE".

```
import React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import {IconButton, Menu, MenuItem } from '@material-ui/core';


 const options = [
'ONE',
'TWO',
'THREE',
];

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;

export default function AdvanceOptionsMenu() {
 const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
 const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
 const [mapList, setMapList] = useState([]);

 const handleClick = (event) => {
   setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
 };

 const handleClose = () => {
  setAnchorEl(null);
 };

 const addMap = (event) => {
  **console.log(event.currentTarget)**
  handleClose();
 };

return (
<>
<div className="advance-menu">
  <IconButton
    aria-label="more"
    aria-controls="long-menu"
    aria-haspopup="true"
    onClick={handleClick}
  >
    <MoreVert />
  </IconButton>
  <Menu
    id="long-menu"
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    keepMounted
    open={open}
    onClose={handleClose}
    PaperProps={{
      style: {
        maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5,
        width: '20ch',
      },
    }}
  >
    {options.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem key={option} selected={option==="ONE"} onClick={addMap}>
        {option}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </Menu>
  </div>
  {mapList}
  </>
);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question link you shared, one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66624930/8876221) suggested using the `event.target.innerText` to get the value. Another approach could be, you can pass a value to the `onClick` in the `MenuItem`. I've created a [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-urt3k?file=/demo.js:1294-1302) for both options. Please review.