# React get data attributes on html tag in onChange handler

Tags: reactjs

I want to use the same `onChange` handler for a series of inputs.

```
<input onChange={this.handleInputChange}
    type="text"
    data-input-name="name"
    value={this.state.name}/>
```

so I am attempting to use this html data attribute to store the input's name. When I go to pull the attribute off in JavaScript, I am unable to access it.

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState([event.target.inputName]: event.target.value})
}
```

I've tried a few permutations to no avail, and it seems difficult to debug since when I log the `event.target` I just see an html element in the JavaScript console.

Any advice on how to better debug this or where my syntax is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've noticed that you have missed an opening curly brace in your `setState` call. And that will throw a syntax error when you run it. It should be fixed like this:

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.inputName]: event.target.value})
}
```

For accessing your data attribute from the `handleInputChange`, you can do it like this:

```
handleInputChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.getAttribute('data-input-name')]: event.target.value,
  });
};
```

And also, you can use the default name attributes that comes with these inputs like this:

```
handleInputChange = event => {
  this.setState({
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
  });
};


// in your render fucntion
<input
  onChange={this.handleInputChange}
  type="text"
  name="name"
  value={this.state.name}
/>
```

This will work as the same as using data attributes. Hope this help!

Comment: Oh neat, is that `.getAttribute` function part of the HtmlElement object type API?

Comment: Yep, it's part of the DOM APIs, according to one of the React core team members.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20383295/1727948

Answer (score 3):

You could pass the input name as an argument instead of having it as a property, like so:

```
<input onChange={(e) => this.handleInputChange(e,"someValue")}
    type="text"
    value={this.state.name}/>
```

and then

```
handleInputChange = (event, name) => {
    this.setState([name]: event.target.value})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was also able to find a somewhat dirty solution to pulling the value off of the event object.

```
event.target.attributes['data-input-name'].value
```