# Odd Behavior With JavaScript OnClick Event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have a React app which has this code:

```
<div className={ mainCss } data-appmode={ AppMode.MAIN } onClick={ this.handleAppModeClick.bind(this) }>
     <div className="NavLinkIconContainer"></div>
     <div>Main</div>
</div>
```

When I click on div with `className="NavLinkIconContainer"` the `handleAppModeClick` function does not work correctly. The function fires but does not pick up the data-* attribute. However, when I click on the div with Main as it's content it works perfectly picking up the data-* attribute. Why is this and how do I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access custom attributes from event object in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377837/how-to-access-custom-attributes-from-event-object-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can the `data-appmode` value from `event.currentTarget.dataset`.

- event - the event object
- [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) - the element with the onClick
- [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset) - an easy access to data-* values

```js
class Demo extends React.Component {
  handleAppModeClick = event => console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.appmode);

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        data-appmode="example" 
        onClick={this.handleAppModeClick}>
           <div className="NavLinkIconContainer">NavLinkIconContainer</div>
           <div>Main</div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo />,
  root
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ori Drori's suggestion will work. Alternatively, you can write your component as

```
<div className={ mainCss } data-appmode={ AppMode.MAIN } onClick={ ()=>this.handleAppModeClick(AppMode.MAIN) }>
 <div className="NavLinkIconContainer"></div>
 <div>Main</div>
```

This will fire off the function with a hard-coded argument. In my opinion, it's a little bit cleaner than using event.currentTarget.dataset. That being said, I am sure that others disagree with me, and if the solution works, it works.

Alternatively, you can use

```
 handleAppModeClick = event => console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-appmode'));
```

to get the data from the actual element.