# React - Creating a form with a dynamic number of inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to create a form for a user to submit a recipe. I need to get it set up to where the user can click the "+" button to add more ingredients or add more instructions. There's also a "-" button next to each input to remove it.

I have this mostly working, I can add items. However deleting the items does not seem to work with any consistency.

I am using Material UI, I am not certain if that is relevant.

Here are the relevant bits of code I am working on, I will link a full codesandbox at the end.

```
const [ingredients, setIngredients] = React.useState(
  [
    {
      name: "",
      amount: ""
    }
  ]
);
```

Here is how I am rendering the array in react

```
        {ingredients.map((ing, idx) => {
          return (
            <div key={idx}>
              <TextField
                id={"ing-name-" + idx}
                name={"ing-name-" + idx}
                variant="outlined"
                label="Ingrediant Name"
                value={ing.name}
                required
                onChange={handleIngredientChange}
              />
              <TextField
                id={"ing-amt-" + idx}
                name={"ing-amt-" + idx}
                variant="outlined"
                label="Ingredient Amount"
                value={ing.amount}
                required
                onChange={handleIngredientChange}
              />
              <Button
                id={"ing-remove-" + idx}
                variant="contained"
                color="secondary"
                type="button"
                onClick={handleIngredientRemove}
              >-</Button>
            </div>
          )
        })}

        <Button
          variant="contained"
          color="primary"
          type="button"
          onClick={handleIngredientAdd}
        >+</Button>
```

And finally here are the two functions handling the add / remove of the items

```
  function handleIngredientRemove(event) {
    /*
    * To remove an element, we just use the array.filter function to genereate a new array without the 
    * element being deleted
    */
    console.log(event.target.id);
    let idx = parseInt(event.target.id.split("-")[2]);
    console.log("Removing ingredient " + idx);
    let newIngredients = ingredients.filter((ingredient, index) => idx !== index);
    setIngredients(newIngredients);
    
  }

  function handleIngredientAdd(event) {
    /*
    * Same concept as the above methods, concat returns a new array. In this case we get a new array with an
    * element containing an empty string in both fields at the end of it
    */
    let newIngredients = ingredients.concat({name: "", amount: ""});
    setIngredients(newIngredients);
  }
```

Full codesandbox demo https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-herschel-k0oqf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Material UI wraps your button with multiple tags. So when you click on a button, there might be something else inside was clicked.

Pass id to onClick function will solve your problem but it might create a new function every time when you click the button.

```
onClick={() => handleIngredientRemove(idx)}
```

I suggest you use [currentTarget](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46349960/8546128) instead of current.

```
function handleInstructionRemove(event) {
    // Use event.currentTarget instead of event.current
    let idx = parseInt(event.currentTarget.id.split("-")[2]);
    console.log("Removing instruction " + idx);
    let newinstructions = instructions.filter(
          (instruction, index) => idx !== index
    );
    setInstructions(newinstructions);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried out both of these solutions and they both work. I think I will use the currentTarget like suggested.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way would be to pass the index to the delete handler and filter with that index.(only changed for first form)
[here is the updated code](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-swanson-b6dmq)

or you can use the timestamp as an id at the time of adding and using that unique timestamp id to delete

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not to parse element id to extract an index. You could pass it directly:

```
onClick={() => handleIngredientRemove(idx)}
```

Then catch it in `handleIngredientRemove` like

```
handleIngredientRemove(idx)
```

Now it deletes fine!

Comment: your idx become event. it should be () => handleIngredientRemove(idx)

Comment: Thank you! Fixed