# How do I get data set from a tr element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I was working on my react project and I put an `onClick` function and dataset to my `<tr>` element like this

```
<tr key={index} onClick={ev} data-ti={ddd.id} className={classs}>
```

and so in that `ev` function I tried to get the value from the dataset like this

```
function ev(e){

    const {ti} = e.target.dataset

   console.log(ti) // returns undefined
}
```

and instead of returning an id it returns `undefined` am I doing something wrong or maybe there's another way of doing it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664414/1051677 That's one way to do it but I'm surprised `e.target.dataset` doesn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10086501/1051677 maybe use `currentTarget` instead?

Comment: `event.target` is the element clicked on, `this` is the element whose handler called the listener, so `let ti = this.dataset.ti` is significantly simper and more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely that instead of clicking on the `tr` you're actually clicking on the `td` inside it. So you need to get the `parentNode` of that `td` first, and then grab the data attribute.

```js
const tr = document.querySelector('tr');

tr.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const { target: { parentNode } } = e;
  const { dataset: { ti } } = parentNode;
  console.log(ti);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ti="test">
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'll add Rob's edit here.

```js
const tr = document.querySelector('tr');

tr.addEventListener('click', handleClick, false);

function handleClick(e) {
  const tr = e.target.closest('tr');
  const ti = tr ? tr.dataset.ti : null;
  console.log(ti);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-ti="test">
      <td>Test</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Which presumes that the click is on a td. It might be better to use `let tr = e.target.closest('tr'); let ti = tr? tr.dataset.ti : null;` which is also somewhat more semantic.

Comment: I do keep forgetting about `closest`. Thanks for the heads-up. @RobG

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the event inside your onClick with a variable of the value you want, like `onClick={ev(ddd.id)}`.