# React js : store checkbox id as array along with current date and a boolen value of check box

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have multiple checkboxes i want to store the `id, currentdate, and boolen value` of check box

of all the check boxes that are getting cliked

```
 <div className="accordion-content  tableforsymtm">
                        {this.state.custum.map((personData, key) => {
                          return (
                            <span className="trforsymtm">
                              <td key={personData.id}>
                                <input
                                  data-id={personData.id}
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  checked={personData && personData.positive}
                                  onChange={(e) =>
                                    this.custumhandleCheckClick(
                                      e,
                                      "custum",
                                      key
                                    )
                                  }
                                 
                                />
                              </td>
                              <td className="tdoneline">
                                {personData.symptom}
                              </td>
                            </span>
                          );
                        })}
                      </div>
```

I want  to store data like below in state

I want to store it like this because I want to pass the data to API only when I click on a submit button

```
[
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 6,
        "boolvalue" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 5,
        "boolvalue" : false
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" :7,
        "boolvalue" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 11,
        "boolvalue" : true
    },
    {
        "date" : "2022-02-15",
        "id" : 4,
        "boolvalue" : false
    }
]
```

Comment: check this question: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20377837/how-to-access-custom-attributes-from-event-object-in-react`

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh the abouve question doesnot help me

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh https://codesandbox.io/s/lpd3d?file=/src/App.js:1341-1351

Comment: i found a similar code sandbox but this one uses react hook unfortunatily i want the example in class component

Comment: you should get data attributes value

Comment: can u help me with a codesandbox example

Comment: that's really easy: `<Input data-xxx="hello" />` then: `const onChecked = (e) => e.target.dataset.xxx`

Comment: @MohammadEsmaeilzadeh pls help me with a workingexample